# Traversing values from one page to the other page

Tags: asp.net, request.querystring

I have 2 aspx pages.. `(view.aspx,edit.aspx)`.
under `view.aspx` I have grid which displays the following fields.
`class,photo,photocaption,Edit` which consists of class name, image of the class and a caption for the photo and a link button for edit which traverses to `edit.aspx`...

under `edit.aspx`, I have a table consisting of

```
Class(a drop down box),
Photo(text box with BROWSE button),
photocaption(Textbox).
```

when i click on the edit in `view.aspx`, I must get the entered values in the `view.aspx` grid by default in `edit.aspx` table..

Please help me to finish my Task...

Comment: Just to make sure, what do you mean by a 'grid'? Did you mean the GridView control?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik : i am trying using request.querystring but nt able to understand it properly ..

Comment: @JWLim ; In view.aspx i have few text boxes and a view button.. when i click o the view button i am displaying the above mentioned columns in a datagrid format..

Comment: If you want to redirect to a page from the link, why do you use `Request.QueryString`? Instead you can use `PostBackURL` property of the link to redirect it to the specific page

Comment: @Shuttler Okay. Is there a `ID` value for your class records, or do you want to rely on something like the class name to determine which class' record to edit?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik If it is a normal redirecting its fine but i need the values to get dissplayed on edit.aspx page.. hope i am clear with wat i need ..

Comment: @JWLim : In datagrid i have the name of the class displayed.. i need the same value to get displayed in drowndown in edit.aspx .. To be more specific i need to Populate the values from the textbox to a dropdown..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `view.aspx` page has a TextBox control for the class name called `txtClassName`, you can add a query string to your `edit.aspx` like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="EditLink" runat="server" Text="Edit" PostBackUrl='<%# "edit.aspx?classname=" + txtClassName.Text %>' />
```

This creates the url in this format:

> edit.aspx?classname=class1

Then, in the `Page_Load` event of your `edit.aspx` page, you can retrieve the selected class name like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string className = Request.QueryString["classname"];

        // code to output the class details      
        // for example, if you want to add the class name to a dropdownlist:
        DropDown1.Items.Add(className);
    }
}
```